# How to get log details for CRUD operations in Mongodb community editions?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new in MongoDB.I need the log details for testing purposes. Log Details about CRUD operations in MongoDB version v3.6.3 community editions?

thanks for the contributions

Comment: By default, you will find the log file here: /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

Comment: but only create queries log is present I need full actions queries

Comment: Increase the profiling level: db.setProfilingLevel(2)